# Conditional overlapping view transparency?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a few moving views which are semi-transparent, at some point they will be overlapping. Is it possible to make the overlapped part "invisible"  through the top most view?
For example, 3 `UIViews` a background (which is stationary) and 2 subviews (the semi-transparent ones) and when they overlap the lower subview will be "invisible" under the top subview, all the while i can still see the background view and the part of the lower subview which isn't overlapping the other view.
Here's an image to help clarify the before and after they overlap.

Before Overlap:

[image: Before Image]
After Overlap:
[image: After Image]
(the view on the far right looks a little strange because it blends with the white background)

Comment: didn't you try to bring that subview to front ? using [self.view bringSubviewToFront:stationaryView];

Comment: the stationary is supposed to be visible, its the black view (in the image) that shouldn't be visible when it overlaps

Comment: is it a must to make them semi-transparent ?

Comment: Yes, the sub views must be semi transparent (while the view isn't necessarily transparent the image itself in the view is a semitransparent image)